# CSS3 image transitioning without hover

Tags: image, css, transition

I am trying to find a transitioning CSS code to transition two images. I want the first image to be shown for 4 seconds then fade into a second image which will stay the same for for seconds then fade back to the first. Right now I am not using CSS and am finding most CSS tutorials are formatted for an on :hoover. I want my image to constantly change without a :hover being needed.

The flexi ad coding I am using now is a  ans works fine in waterfox and explorer but you can see the images being loaded in chrome with a bad flicker.

Here's the example of what I am working with. The script I am using now is actually transitioning through 30 images i made some that fade from one to the next and thats why it looks like it fades. I would like some kind of CSS that will only require 2 images and fade one to the next every 4 seconds.

http://www.vulgarmediaproductions.com/walt/walt.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**keyframe animations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes) for this - [**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3613962)

HTML:

```
<img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2012-10-a-web.jpg'>
<img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2004-45-a-web.jpg'>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    width : 320px;
    height: 180px;
}
img:last-child { animation: fader 4s infinite alternate; }
@keyframes fader { to { opacity: 0; } }
```

---

**EDIT**

If your images have transparency, then you'll need to animate the opacity for both of them, not just for the one on top. Like this - [**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3618445)

```
img {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width : 256px;
    height: 256px;
}
img:first-child { animation: fadein 8s infinite alternate; }
img:last-child { opacity: 1; animation: fadeout 8s infinite alternate; }
@keyframes fadein { 50% { opacity: 1; } }
@keyframes fadeout { 50% { opacity: 0; } }
```

Also, keep in mind that you'll have to use prefixes (I did not use any since dabblet includes -prefix-free and it's easier to highlight the idea that way):

```
img:first-child {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 8s infinite alternate;  /* Chrome, Safari, Android, Blackberry */
    -moz-animation: fadein 8s infinite alternate; /* FF, FF for Android */
    -o-animation: fadein 8s infinite alternate; /* Opera 12 */
    animation: fadein 8s infinite alternate; /* IE 10, FF 16+, Opera 12.5 */
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { 50% { opacity: 1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadein { 50% { opacity: 1; } }
@-o-keyframes fadein { 50% { opacity: 1; } }
@keyframes fadein { 50% { opacity: 1; } }
/* same for the other set (fadeout) */
```

Comment: @Ana.. Working fine :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not tested and just written on the fly, but should work.
If you have any problems getting it to work, let me know...
You may want to debug this using FireBug for Firefox. It helps you alot playing arround with CSS, HTML and JavaScript.

**CSS3:**

```
.slideShow
{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
-ie-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
.slideShowWrapper { position:relative; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slideShowWrapper" id="mySlideShow" style="width:400px;height:300px;">
   <div class="slideShow" style="opacity:1.0"> (image 1 goes here) </div>
   <div class="slideShow" style="opacity:0.0"> (image . goes here) </div>
   <div class="slideShow" style="opacity:0.0"> (image . goes here) </div>
   <div class="slideShow" style="opacity:0.0"> (image N goes here) </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function ssCycle(_obj)
{
   var _oList=_obj.getElementsByTagName('div');
   for (var _trace=0;_trace<oList.length;_trace++)      
   {
      if(_oList[_trace].getAttribute('style').indexOf('opacity:1.0')>0)
      {
         _oList[_trace].style.opacity='0.0';
         try
         {
            _oList[(_trace+1)].style.opacity='1.0';
         }
         catch(_e)
         {
            _oList[0].style.opacity='1.0';
         }
      }
   }
};
(function(_src){ void(var tmrFunc = "void(ssCycle(document.getElementById("+_src+"));";setInterval(tmrFunc,4000);}).call('mySlideShow');
```